# Can't get full result set in R DBI

Tags: r, r-dbi

That database is Oracle 12. I'm using R DBI with RODBC.

I have a complex query with multiple sub queries and WITH statements. The result set is only about 3000 rows, but it only returns 800 in R, and *exactly* 800 rows every time.

I've tried dbSendQuery followed by dbFetch, or just dbGetQuery by itself, setting n = 5000 and other values that are supposed to return all rows, but nothing works. I can successfully get *less* than 800 rows by setting n = 500, but not any more than 800.

As I add columns to the SELECT statement, the # of rows returned decreases. It isn't a JOIN issue, the full query works fine when running it natively, just not in R.

I've also tried getting results in chunks, using code as follows, but it will only obtain the first chunk before ending the loop and returning a value that says the full results have been reached:

```
while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
    chunk <- dbFetch(rs, 100)
    print(nrow(chunk))
}
```

If I keep all WITH statements the same and retain all sub-queries, but reduce the final SELECT a single column from each WITH or sub-query, it's fine, I get all rows. And as I said, the full query works fine natively in SQL Developer.

It seems like there may be some size/memory limit, but for 3000 rows that shouldn't be an issue, and in any case I have tons of RAM, and the amount of resources being used by R when sending & fetching results in negligible, and the dataset is tiny. It's only the query that's complex.

Comment: I didn't think `RODBC` uses the `DBI` interface. Do you mean the [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) package?

Comment: Please post a sample of SQL query. Need to understand content. Possibly you are not running the *same* query in R or Oracle. Procedural semantics of PL/SQL like `IF` cannot be run in R `dbGetQuery` calls.

Comment: @r2evans: I'm using RODBC with another package RODBCDBI that wraps both. So my initializing code is something like:
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(RODBCDBI)

con <- dbConnect(RODBCDBI::ODBC(), dsn.= ....

Comment: ahhh, I forgot about `RODBCDBI`, tx

Comment: I don't know that `RODBCDBI` is not part of the problem, are you able to reproduce the issue using (perhaps) `odbc`? (`RODBCDBI` is over 4 years unupdated.) The test *might* be as simple as `con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)`.

Comment: @Parfait Not using any PL/SQL specific functions. Just WITH statements and JOIN.  The WITH statements are straight-forward SELECT queries, conditional JOINs. In SQL Developer it runs in about 20 seconds. I can't really post the SQL for security reasons. You'll just have to take my word that it's just SELECT statements and JOINs. As I said in my question, removing columns yields the correct # of rows: SELECT col1 is fine. SELECT col1, col2, col3 returns half the results. SELECT col1 ... col5 returns even less. Always in blocks of 100, so it will be 1900 rows, then 1100, then 800.

Comment: Is any field a large CLOB, BLOB, or unlimited text fields? Numbers with very high precision? Or even extended types like XML or JSON? ODBC driver might have a cache or read limit. Try adding columns one at a time to isolate the problem one. What are the types for `col2`. `col3`, etc.? Maybe even call `CAST` to convert to known, shorter types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem was an invalid value in the results returned. The query worked fine in SQL Developer because that only returns results in chunks of 50. R DBI / RODBC fetches the full result set, though also in chunks (apparently) of 100, which is why it always fetched a round number of records: the 800+ block had the invalid value, so it only fetched the first 800 before getting an error.

Even trying to export query results from Developer didn't reveal the specific error, it simple failed. I had to page through all of the results to find the value in question and fix it. After that, everything worked fine.